# Delay time when get photo from "API" in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Taking image from internet takes too much time how can I show the page only after complete loading the image.

Comment: Image.network('https://googleflutter.com/sample_image.jpg'), I used this image

Comment: Future await then push the page, show a loading icon, make shimmer, ... The best thing (in term of UI) should be the shimmer.

Comment: This is help full but I want that the page comes with the image no loading and no shimmer

Comment: In theory it's good, but in practice it won't work. If nothing is displayed (no connection), without loading, without anything the user will take it as a bug. You must always have a return on a given action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this library [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) for do this task its show place holder or loading until image loading from server after its cache it and not need to load again and again in for example:

With a placeholder:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
 ),
```

Or with a progress indicator:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) => 
            CircularProgressIndicator(value: downloadProgress.progress),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
 ),
```